# Can Python multiprocessing process be launched from OTHER than __main__?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, debian

I am writing a framework in Python 3.8 on Debian that will launch some multiprocessing processes.  I want the configuration and launching of the processes to be done in functions OTHER than the **main**. The **main** file will be written by the end user of the framework and they should not need to know about these processes. Hence I tried to put the code that configures and launches the processes in helper functions or class methods that the **main** will call.

What I'm finding is as soon as the launcher function / method exits the processes die. This is even though the launcher functions / methods run (I think) in the same process as **main** which is still running.  I have put a long time.sleep in the launcher functions / methods right before they exit and it seems the processes are alive for that long.

I tried setting the 'daemon' flag but that doesn't seem to solve it.  If this is truly a limitation of multiprocessing I can instruct the users of my framework to always put some boiler-plate launcher code in their file, but it seems clunky.  All help is appreciated!

Comment: I found some old code of mine where I DID successfully launch processes from outside of __main__. Not sure why I'm unable to do so now. I will post once I figure it out.

Comment: The old code was run using Python3.7. I thought this might be a Python3.8-specific problem, but that seems to NOT be the case: having trouble with Python3.7 as well. Trying to see what is different between my current code and the old one...

Answer (score 0):

The function that launches the processes was returning only the processes to **main** and NOT managed queues that the processes were using. I changed to return a dict with the processes AND the managed queues and everything works.  This is even though **main** does NOT use the queues.